How do I make a DT_I4 Integer lookup from a boolean condition in a derived column to an Integer lookup column? Only a `0` matches, a `1` does not
In order to make a lookup, make:

a derived column in as the four bytes Integer DT_I4 input that can be a 0 or 1,
a lookup to a lookup table column that is a four bytes integer 0 or 1 as well.

Source column:
(DT_I4)(Check1 == "Check1_value")
Lookup column:
See:

Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL) - Microsoft Learn
select without from - modern SQL

select * from 
values(0,'output_for_0')
,(1,'output_for_1')
t (lkp_value, lkp_output)

With other columns to lookup or output, it could look like:

If I do not cast the 0 and 1 to a chosen data type, it becomes an Integer. I take Integers since I want to spare the work to cast each Integer to a bit data type as you have to do that for every value in the whole lookup table query. If you have just the two lines, you might say that it does not matter to write:
select * from 
values(cast(0 as bit),cast('output_for_0' as varchar(100)))
,(cast(1 as bit),cast('output_for_1' as varchar(100)))
t (lkp_value, lkp_output)

But I like to keep it in plain Integers to spare me the nasty casts for each value. I do the same with the other columns, i do not set the varchar length of the text columns and so on, so that my varchars become varchar(45) in the lookup table but are varchar(100) in the input and destination tables. You might do it in another way.
Only the 0 to 0 lookup works while the 1 to 1 lookup does not although both are of the same datatype.
Both (DT_I4)(Check1 == "Check1_value" and the lookup value 1 become the DT_I4 Integer 1 if the condition is met, I passed the number of the derived column to a destination table to double check this.
What do I need to do to make a lookup on integer numbers coming from a boolean condition in a derived column that is cast as an Integer?

While checking this, I tried a 2 instead of a 1, and only since I needed an "if-when-else" for that, I wrote:
(DT_I4)(Check1 == "Check1_value" ? 2 : 0)

and mapped that to the lookup table for which I changed the column from 1 to 2 as well. And it worked. I then changed 2 to 1:
(DT_I4)(Check1 == "Check1_value" ? 1 : 0)

and it worked as well.
Thus, you have to code with "if-when-else" even though the data type output is the same DT_I4 on both sides if you do not.
I do not know why this happens. You find other strange things about the SSIS lookup, for example:

how to identify why lookup failed in SSIS - DBA SE:

SSIS lookups are actually .net string comparisons.
That might tell why the Integer 0 or 1 of a Boolean is not treated the same as the Integer of an "if-then-0-else-1" condition.


SSIS Lookup Transformation No Match Output Only Populates Null - Stack Overflow

PS
This does not help:
(DT_I4)(DT_I1)(Check1 == "Check1_value")

Or:
(DT_I4)(DT_BOOL)(Check1 == "Check1_value")

